# Listviews in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

```
string title = HardwareInfo.GetComputerName().ToString();
        TabPage myTabPage = new TabPage(title);
        // tabControl1.TabPages.Add(myTabPage);

        // Create Column Headers

        ListView listView2 = new ListView();
        ColumnHeader columnA = new ColumnHeader();
        columnA.Text = "adsasd";
        columnA.Width = 185;
        columnA.TextAlign = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
        ColumnHeader columnB = new ColumnHeader();
        columnB.Text = "asd";
        columnB.Width = 185;
        columnB.TextAlign = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
        ColumnHeader columnC = new ColumnHeader();
        columnC.Text = "asdasd";
        columnC.Width = 185;
        columnC.TextAlign = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
        ColumnHeader columnD = new ColumnHeader();
        columnD.Text = "xx";
        columnD.Width = 185;
        columnD.TextAlign = HorizontalAlignment.Left;

      //  Add columns to the ListView:
          listView2.Columns.Add(columnA);
          listView2.Columns.Add(columnB);
          listView2.Columns.Add(columnC);
          listView2.Columns.Add(columnD);

          listView2.Size = new Size(800, 300);
          listView2.Location = new Point(0, 0);
          listView2.GridLines = true;
          listView2.View = View.Details;
```

Here I have a copy of some of my Code, and what I am looking to do is get a list of computers on my next work, then create tabs for each computer. I have that part done perfectly fine, but the issue I am having is that, it creates the listviews with the same NAME and that is causing an obvious problem when I try and add information to those specific list views. I was wondering, how would I go about giving each listview a name of the computer for example. As you can see for my tabs I can do that, but when it comes to the list views, if i try and do the same type of assign a string title to where it says Listview listview2 It wont let me compile. I'm new to programming and I apologize if this is obvious. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to create a `List<ListView>` and add your listviews to it.

Depending on how you use it, you may want a dictionary instead.

Comment: Well I want to store different information for each computer on each list view, and if they have the same names the information keeps getting put in the same places. So i just want to distinguish them from each other

Answer (score 0):

If i understand the question what you want is the name variable, in this case

```
listView2.name = <name of listview2>
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview_members(v=vs.71)

But i think you should look into using functions with a returntype of columns for those column constructor parts.

Comment: Yeah I can name the list, but the issue is, even if i say listView2.Name  = ""; and set the name, that doesnt seem like it effects where the information goes. Because when I add items to the list view i end up using listView2.Items.Add(lvi1); and regardless what I name it. the data goes to "Listview2" and no matter how many computers I have, if they all create list views with the name Listview2, they just fill their data ontop of eachother or no?

Comment: Ahh. You never said that the code provided was in a for loop, this changes the question, i would refer you to the answer that SLaks provided. For future reference the name you are referring to in your post is called a "variable name", or just "variable", not just name.

Answer (score 0):

You want the to make the variable that stores the listview part of a dictionary, this way you can look up the different computers by their name, or whatever string you desire

```
Dictionary<string, ListView>
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx

You could use a List if you don't need the lookup portion of the dictionary, but is fine with using integers as with an array

```
List<ListView>
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx